# Append element to div starting at the bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('#parent').append('<div>element</div>');
});
```

```css
 #parent {
   height: 200px;
   width: 100px;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent"></div>
<button>
  Add
</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8ybnycxv/1/

When the button is clicked, I want to append a div element to the `#parent`. However, if there is no element in the `#parent` yet, elements will be added starting at the **bottom** of the `#parent`. How can I do that?

Edit: added the demonstrating picture

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "elements will be added starting at the bottom"

Comment: _elements will be added starting at the bottom of the #parent_.. inside or outside the parent?

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/8ybnycxv/3/

Comment: I added a picture to demonstrate my question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Setting `vertical-align:bottom` will work

```js
$('button').click(function() {
    $('#parent').append('<div>element</div>');
});
```

```css
#parent {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script><div id="parent"></div>
<button>
Add
</button>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `transform: rotate(180deg)`

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/8ybnycxv/4/)

```
.rotate{
 transform: rotate(180deg);
 }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for for hours.

Answer (score 1):

[Abhishek Pandey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6670723/abhishek-pandey)'s answer solved my question. However, in some cases, `display: table-cell` might not work as expected because it has some drawbacks:

- It does not work with overflow (needs to be wrapped in a div)
- It needs to be wrapped in a parent with `display: table` to have 100% width (otherwise, we need to do some hack like set width to 1000000px)

I just found other way to solve my question by using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```
<div id="parent"></div>
<button>
Add
</button>

#parent {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

var i = 0;
$('button').click(function() {
    $('#parent').prepend('<div>element' + (++i) + '</div>');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j23otgx0/4/

Note since the flex direction is `column-reverse`, we need to change jquery function to `prepend()` instead of `append()`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean this?

```js
$('button').click(function() {
 $('#parent .container').append('<div>element</div>');
});
```

```css
#parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;  
}

#parent .container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent"><div class="container"></div></div>
<button>
Add
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a different case and found a solution, maybe it could help someone:

I have a div (container) and appending draggable items inside of it with multiple rows, and using:

`transform: rotate(180deg)` screwed the draggable functionality so:

as for the container or parent:

```
.parent{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: flex-start;
}

$('button').click(function() {
    $('.parent').append('<div>element</div>');
});
```