# How can i create chat like UI in html and css

Tags: html, css

I need to create a chat container box with chat message A, B, C, D

1. A
2. B
3. C
4. D

latest message should be added to bottom always.

I used

display : flex;
flex-direction : column-reverse.

it will show from bottom but latest message adding to top like this

1. D
2. C
3. B
4. A

how to achieve  like this

1. A
2. B
3. C
4. D

Comment: display: flex; flex-direction: column;

Comment: this would come from top to bottom. I actually looking for bottom to top with latest message always added to bottom of the chat like normal chat UI.

Comment: Now it is not clear to me what exactly you want. Give more explanation, pls.

Comment: I am trying to create chat UI. when ever i send add new message it should push to bottom of the chat window. but it add top to the chat window.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39741194/append-element-to-div-starting-at-the-bottom This is solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

To add latest messages to bottom try using
`display:flex;flex-direction:column;`

here is the reference link to see other flex properties:
[1]: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

Use unshift to append the latest message to the beginning of the list `conversation.unshift(latestMessage);` and then format with `display : flex; flex-direction : column-reverse`